# Migrating user passwords from Symfony to Django

Tags: django, symfony, hash, passwords, salt

I want to migrate users from Symfony to Django. I want to save same passwords for users.
I have hashes of user passwords in Symfony and salt.
How to migrate hashes of user passwords from Symfony to Django?

Comment: Please supply us with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably going to have to implement a custom password hasher which you'll add to the list of hashers in settings.py.

You use this hasher to check passwords and authenticate users, and then (optionally) replace these old hashes with standard Django based hashes.

Here's an example of a [hasher](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/3030/) for Drupal which might help you get started.

Comment: Tnx Rix!
I think it is the best way.